# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - using csv2geojson in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, geojson

I'm using [csv2geojson](https://github.com/mapbox/csv2geojson) module in a node.js app to read a csv file and eventually parse it to geojson. But getting the error in title when running my app.

Here is the block of code running that gets the error:

```
var csv2geojson = require('csv2geojson');
var fs = require('fs');

var csvfile = fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../public/json/locations/wireless-locs.csv', 'utf8');
var geoJson = csv2geojson.csv2geojson(csvfile, function(err, results) {
 console.log(geoJson);
});
```

Error in console:

```
/Users/../../../sites/node/app/node_modules/csv2geojson/index.js:109
    if (!parsed.length) {
           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Example of my csv file:

```
LAT LON NAME    TIME    CELL_ID
-32.62678025    151.39455296    LOC1    2017-06-14  1234
-37.80774968    140.72863036    LOC2    2017-06-14  1235
```

Comment: This looks like TSV not CSV

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(fs.existsSync(__dirname + '/../public/json/locations/wireless-locs.csv'));`

Comment: @BertrandMartel Hi Bert, the output was True

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
var csv2geojson = require('csv2geojson');
var fs = require('fs');

var csvfile = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../public/json/locations/wireless-locs.csv', 'utf8');
console.log(csvfile);
var geoJson = csv2geojson.csv2geojson(csvfile, function(err, results) {
     console.log(results);
});
```

Your code have two issues:

One is you are using asynchronous read file function, you need to change it to synchronous version or write your following code in the callback function.

Another one is you should log the results rather than geoJson variable, results is the results of converted data.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for the reply. i used this as a test.csv and still got the same error

Comment: Try this simple one. And also make sure the csv's path is correct in your js file.

Comment: Still same results.

Comment: I've used this site: http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-geojson.htm to load my CSV file and it converts it to geoJson with no issues...

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there are any errors when calling [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback). You can do that by modifying the function call to include a callback which contains `error` and `data` parameters:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../public/json/locations/wireless-locs.csv', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    var geoJson = csv2geojson.csv2geojson(data, function(err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(results);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Pat, added this in and got some different outputs in the logs.      `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
  `at Object.csv2geojson (/Users/../../../../node/heat_mapping/node_modules/csv2geojson/index.js:109:16)`
    `at fs.readFile (/Users/../../../../node/heat_mapping/routes/index.js:22:29)`
    `at tryToString (fs.js:456:3)`
`at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:443:12)`